# Is it possible for a golang struct to be extended?

Tags: go, struct, syntax, compilation

I'm working on a new golang project (it's a bit messy), and I'm running into a very strange scenario. A struct does not have a data member defined, but the rest of the code is using the non-existant data member. Here is the example:

```
type Data struct {
    Mount   string
    MinSize uint64
}
```

When `Data` is initialized and passed around there's a function that's using `Data.PrevMount`, and I don't understand how that's working, since it's not defined in the struct.

For example in my main.go, if I do the following, it compiles perfectly

```
   data, err := LoadData(config)
   data.PrevMount = nil
```

When I try this in my main.go, I get an error:

```
   data, err := LoadData(config)
   data.PrevMounts = nil
```

```
main.go:137:12: data.PrevMounts undefined (type *Data has no field or method PrevMounts)
```

My question, is how the hell does the compiler allow `data.PrevMount` to be used all over the code when it's not defined in the struct definition? I don't see anywhere in the code a definition for `PrevMount`. What should I be looking for? Is there some go language feature I'm unaware of.

Comment: The only explanation is that the `Data` returned by `LoadData` is not the same as the `Data` you show. There are at least two `Data` types in two different packages.

Comment: definitely there will be two Data data type , check which one getting import in the main.go file